# Transferring the Contents of a Folder Using smbclient

Tags: shell, ftp, smb

I have written a Shell script that moves into a directory with some binaries files present.

What I am looking to do is transfer all the files present inside this directory.

```
cd /home/user/binaries
smbclient //ip.address/directory$ password -W domain -U username << ENDOFMYSMBCOMMANDS
prompt
put *
exit
ENDOFMYSMBCOMMANDS
```

I tried to use `put *` to transfer all files - but this is not accepted.

The only other option I know of is to go one folder up, and use the command `mput binaries` - but this  copies everything including the folder.

How can I modify my script to only transfer the contents of the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the answer with me all along!!  I was under the impression that `mput` could only  be used to transfer a directory, turns out that using `mput *` inside a directory will copy all the files located within that directory!

```
cd /home/user/binaries
smbclient //ip.address/directory$ password -W domain -U username << ENDOFMYSMBCOMMANDS
prompt
put *
exit
ENDOFMYSMBCOMMANDS
```

Going to leave this here for anyone else who gets stumped on this like me!

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to format the self-answer of Dustin a bit differently into a real one-liner. It is also possible to add the prepended "cd" command into the smbclient command, like so:

```
smbclient //ip.address/directory -W domain -U username \
-c 'prompt OFF; recurse ON; cd remote/target/directory; lcd /local/source/directory; mput *'
```